# What is difference of the two lengths in pcap's packet header?

Tags: pcap

Here is the structure of the packet header in pcap:

```
struct pcap_pkthdr {
    struct timeval ts;  /* time stamp */
    bpf_u_int32 caplen; /* length of portion present */
    bpf_u_int32 len;    /* length this packet (off wire)*/
};
```

I wonder what is the real difference between `caplen` and `len`? And where are they used?

Answer (score 1):

`len` is the actual length of the packet on the wire. `caplen` is the length which is captured and thus present in the pcap file. `caplen` can be the same but also smaller than `len`.

How many bytes of a packet will be captured can be specified for example in `tcpdump` with `-s size`. While on many system tcpdump will capture up to 64k by default for example on OpenBSD it will only capture 116 bytes by default.